# Collapse and Expand UINavigationBar with "Prefer Large Title" programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm create a new clean Xcode project with a "UITabBarController" and UIViewController (embedded in "UINavigationController").

The "UINavigationController" has enable "Prefer Large Title" to 'always'.

I add two IBAction for collapse/expand in the "UIViewController"" for the NavigationBar", but the follow code not works. After my research I read, i must set `prefersLargeTitles` to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but nothing happens when the IBAction calls.

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = TRUE;
}

-(IBAction)collapse:(id)sender  {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = FALSE;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
}

-(IBAction)expand:(id)sender  {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = TRUE;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAlways;
}

@end
```

How i can collapse and expand the UINavigationbar programmatically ?

Comment: Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;`

Comment: @RodrigoMorbach Works. Thanks.